# Counting the number of times a certain position is shown in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have a list of "clients" that I need to count how many times in every line this "element" shows up. a little snippet of the text file inside the .zip [FakeCostomers](http://www.cs.uni.edu//~diesburg/courses/cs1510_sp20/labs/lab12/FakeCustomerData.zip):

```
1,female,Melissa,J,Palmer,4 Lynch Street,Milwaukee,WI,53213,US,Melissa.J.Palmer@gmail.com,920-959-8247,9/29/1972,Visa,281.84,5

2,male,Edwin,M,Corder,4302 Pick Street,RIDGEWAY,CO,81432,US,Edwin.M.Corder@outlook.com,970-626-1897,2/28/1953,Visa,277.58,16

3,female,Laura,A,Olvera,365 Tori Lane,Salt Lake City,UT,84116,US,Laura.A.Olvera@yahoo.com,801-599-5964,4/11/1963,MasterCard,560.63,24

4,male,Wayne,D,Adams,3643 Nash Street,Chicago,IL,60605,US,Wayne.D.Adams@yahoo.com,312-948-6927,7/16/1957,Visa,320.11,3

5,female,Mari,R,Smith,3024 Atha Drive,Palmdale,CA,93550,US,Mari.R.Smith@gmail.com,661-574-4919,7/30/1973,MasterCard,798.58,28

6,male,Craig,H,Salazar,3929 Goosetown Drive,Hendersonville,NC,28792,US,Craig.H.Salazar@gmail.com,828-697-6697,1/15/1959,Visa,183.35,29

7,male,Henry,S,Clark,205 Charla Lane,Mesquite,TX,75150,US,Henry.S.Clark@gmail.com,972-686-5507,8/28/1962,Visa,650.58,27

8,male,Jerry,L,Littleton,1652 My Drive,Elmsford,NY,10523,US,Jerry.L.Littleton@gmail.com,347-219-4091,9/5/1975,MasterCard,525.73,8

9,female,Georgia,V,Allen,1226 Jefferson Street,Norfolk,VA,23510,US,Georgia.V.Allen@yahoo.com,757-774-4490,5/17/1952,Visa,910.39,6

10,male,Ted,A,Harding,2143 Lake Floyd Circle,HOCKESSIN,DE,19707,US,Ted.A.Harding@gmail.com,302-239-3674,7/12/1958,MasterCard,307.51,25

11,male,Jose,J,Houston,2639 Olive Street,Shelby,OH,44875,US,Jose.J.Houston@gmail.com,419-342-5793,4/23/1943,Visa,447.97,27
```

For example if I wanted to find out how many females there are in this list.

So far I have tried:

```
def getColumnDistribution(filename,columnNum):

    file = open(filename,"r")
    listoflists = []

    for line in file:

        stripped_line = line.strip()

        line_list = stripped_line.split()

        listoflists.append(line_list)

        NUMBER = line_list.count(line_list[columnNum])
```

it keeps coming up with `"list index out of range"`
Anyone know how I can fix it or use a better method?

Comment: The python code indentation messed up. Please fix that in the first place

Comment: Your file is CSV, you should treat it as such. Have a look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv). Note that you split on whitespace in your current code, while you should do it on commas. But as already said, use modules that will do it right for you.

Comment: I would recommend to use csv module and list comprehension to solve your problem Please provide csv file.

Comment: it is a .txt file not csv

Comment: It _is_ a CSV file, no matter what extension you add to it. It is _comma_-separated, and you get the error because you split by whitespace, not by commas.

Answer (score 1):

Python gives you a lot of tools that make these kind of tasks painless. For example, you can pass the issues of csv parsing to the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and counter to [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Then it's just a couple lines:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)    # pop off the header row

    genderCounts = Counter(row[1] for row in reader)

print(genderCounts['female'])
# 15167

print(genderCounts['male'])
# 14833
```

If you use the [`Dictreader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) from csv, you can index by columns name, which makes the code more readable:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    genderCounts = Counter(row['Gender'] for row in reader)
```

Of course if you are doing a lot of work on data like this, pandas will make you life substantially easier:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path)
df['Gender'].value_counts()

# female    15167
# male      14833
# Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Tested on 3.6v

```
import csv

def openFile(file_name:str)->tuple:
    with open(file_name,'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        return tuple(csv_reader)  

def getColumnDistribution(csv_data:tuple,name_to_count:str)->int:

    num_of_count = [idx for idx,rows in enumerate(csv_data) if name_to_count in rows]
    print("number of occurence:",num_of_count)
    return len(num_of_count)

#driver code
csv_data = openFile(your_csv_file_name)
getColumnDistribution(csv_data,'female')
```